# powershell slow(?) - write names of subfolders to a text file

Tags: powershell

My Powershell script seems slow, when I run the below code in ISE, it keeps running, doesn't stop.

I am trying to write the list of subfolders in a folder(the folder path is in $scratchpart) to a text file. There are >30k subfolders

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-15)
$path = "E:\Data\PathToScratch.txt"
$scratchpath = Get-Content $path -TotalCount 1

Get-ChildItem -Path $scratchpath -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | Add-Content C:\Data\eProposal\POC\ScratchContents.txt
```

Let me know if my approach is not optimal. Ultimately, I will read the text file, zip the subfolders for archival and delete them.

Thanks for your help in advance. I am new to PS, watched few videos on MVA

Comment: I think I would use background jobs (`Start-Job`) for all the top level folders (modulo a given maximum) and combine the results from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Add-Content`, `Set-Content`, and even `Out-File` are notoriously slow in PowerShell.  This is because each call opens the file, writes to it, and closes the handle.  It never does anything more intelligently than that.

That doesn't sound bad until you consider how pipelines work with `Get-ChildItem` (and `Where-Object` and `Select-Object`).  It doesn't wait until it's completed before it begins passing objects into the pipeline.  It starts passes objects as soon as the provider returns them.  For a large result set, this means that the objects are still feeding in the pipeline long after several have finished processing.  Generally speaking, this is great!  It means the system will function more efficiently, and it's why stuff like this:

```
$x = Get-ChildItem;
$x | ForEach-Object { [...] };
```

Is significantly slower than stuff like this:

```
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object { [...] };
```

And it's why stuff like this appears to stall:

```
Get-ChildItem | Sort-Object Name | ForEach-Object { [...] };
```

The `Sort-Object` cmdlet needs to waits until it's received all pipeline objects before it sorts.  It kind of has to to be able to sort.  The sort itself is nearly instantaneous; it's just the cmdlet waiting until it has the full results.

The issue with `Add-Content` is that, well, it experiences the pipeline not as, "Here's a giant string to write once," but instead as, "Here's a string to write.  Here's a string to write.  Here's a string to write.  Here's a string to write."  You'll be sending content to `Add-Content` here line by line.  *Each line* will instantiate a new call to `Add-Content`, requiring the file to open, write, and close.  You'll likely see better performance if you assign the result of `Get-ChildItem [...] | Where-Object [...]` to a variable, and then write the entire variable to the file at once:

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-15);
$path = "E:\Data\PathToScratch.txt";
$scratchpath = Get-Content $path -TotalCount 1;

$Results = Get-ChildItem -Path $scratchpath -Recurse -Force -Directory | `
    Where-Object{$_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | `
    Select-Object -ExpandPropery FullName;

Add-Content C:\Data\eProposal\POC\ScratchContents.txt -Value $Results;
```

However, you might be concerned about memory usage if your results are actually going to be extremely large.  You can actually use `System.IO.StreamWriter` for this purpose, too.  My process improved in speed by nearly two orders of magnitude (from 12 hours to 20 minutes) by switching to `StreamWriter` and also only calling `StreamWriter` when I had about 250 lines to write (that seemed to be the break-even point for `StreamWriter`'s overhead).  But I was parsing all ACLs for user home and group shares for about 10,000 users and nearly 10 TB of data.  Your task might not be as large.

[Here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/linchi_shea/archive/2010/01/04/add-content-and-out-file-are-not-for-performance.aspx)'s a good blog explaining the issue.

Comment: Awesome! I suspected some of what you have written; Thanks for taking time to explain!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have at least PowerShell 3.0? If you do you should be able to reduce the time by filtering out the files since you are returning those as well.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $scratchpath -Recurse -Force -Directory | ...
```

Currently you are returning *all files* and folders then filtering out the files with `$_.PSIsContainer` which would be slower. So should end up with something like this

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $scratchpath -Recurse -Force -Directory | 
    Where-Object{$_.CreationTime -lt $limit } |
    Select-Object -ExpandPropery FullName | 
    Add-Content C:\Data\eProposal\POC\ScratchContents.txt
```

Comment: Thanks @Matt for the reply. The script is still not finishing. Though, I noticed the txt file size increased faster with -Directory option. It looks like after writing all the content, it is waiting for something(?)

Comment: I got rid of -Force and -Recurse also as they are not relevant for my purpose. The script now finishes (in about 1-2 mins). Though, I would like to know why it wasn't earlier.

Comment: You didn't need `recurse`? You are only looking for the first level of folders? The file size should increase faster (since my code so increase performance.) @mantlex